# How to design nanorod

Tags: materials-design, nanostructures, nanoparticles

I know how to create the nanowire using [Materials Studio](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/biovia/products/molecular-modeling-simulation/biovia-materials-studio/).
The difference between the nannowire and the nanorod is the aspect ratio.

But I am not sure where should I fix the width and length of the nanorod.
My system is mixer of $\ce{WO3}$ (space group is $221$; Pm-3m) and WC (Space group is $187$; P-6m2).
We can see it as $\ce{WO_{(3-x)}}$ and $\ce{WC_x}$.

Any help will be very much helpful.

Comment: +1 But if you agree with the formatting for $\ce{WO3}$ I've given you in my last edit: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/posts/5012/revisions then please do the same for $\ce{WC}$ too.

Comment: Do you mean a cocrystal of WO3 and WC? If yes, are you sure they can form a reasonably stable cocrystal? This does not seem likely to me, because the valence of O and C differ.

Comment: Thanks, @wzlchem5, The pristine system is WO3 nanorods with a mixture of WC. It also has an impurity of carbon dots.  The final product I need to design is WO(3−).WC.

Comment: I do not know much about nanorods but I have been constructing structures of Nano particles(Quantum Dots) using Vesta, it seems to be really good with structure modelling. As for adding particular ligands if you want them you can try IQmol for that purpose.

Comment: @wzkchem5 Does astha's answer to your question help it make more sense?

Comment: @NikeDattani Yes, but I cannot answer the OP's question anyway, other than putting up the doubt on the possibility of a cocrystal...

Comment: @ParmeetSinghEP066 Do you think you'd be able to expand that comment into an answer, perhaps about how to try it with iQmol? I'm trying to help clean up the unanswered queue a bit!

Answer (score 7):

So I have been researching Quantum Dots but I will give you some advice on how could you go about creating your structure using VESTA and add ligands using IQ mol. You should watch this video first - [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxO5uLsvkRE.\](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxO5uLsvkRE.%5C)
Moreover at the point where the instructor changes the central atom and uses that to create the bonds what you could do is to change atoms in a row and then use some minimum bond length(this you could get from the desired width). [image]

I got the above image and I think it looks like a nano rod. Further once you have a long cylindrical shape you could adjust the length, the only idea I have for this is to check the distance between the end points and eliminate the atoms on either side.
Totally not an expert but hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Parmeet. I will try this way.